# Loop through all Unicode extended grapheme clusters

Tags: unicode, swift

The question addresses my main goal, but even being able to loop through all unicode scalars might be worthwhile.

In effect I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
for i in 0x0000...0xFFFF
{
    println("\u{i}")
}
```

Obviously with a larger range.  It doesn't seem like you can interpolate strings into the /u escape character so I'm at a lost on how to do it.

Comment: You can do this:  println("\\u{\\(i)}") to print out the values - i.e. \u{0}
\u{1} etc Note the two backslashes on before the u

Comment: It doesn't look like that actually prints out the unicode for that, I'm just getting:

\u{4096}\u{4097}\u{4098}\u{4099}\u{4100}\u{4101}\u{4102}\u{4103}\u{4104}\u{4105}\u{4106}\u{4107}\u{4108}\u{4109}\u{4110}\u{4111}\u{4112}

Comment: Yes, that's what I said after the "i.e.". I thought you were asking about interpolating strings with \u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `UnicodeScaler` from a `UInt8`, `UInt16`, or `UInt32` and then print that:

```
for i in 0x1000...0x1009 {
    let c = UnicodeScalar(i)
    print(c)
}
```

Outputs:

> က ခ ဂ ဃ င စ ဆ ဇ ဈ ဉ